# If$f$ is injective, then $g$ is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Let $f : A \to \mathbb R$ be a function, where $A$ is some set, and define a new function  $g : A \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x) = 3 \left( f(x) \right)^2 + 1 \;.
$$

I know that if $g$ is injective, then $f$ is injective. How do I know if the converse is true, i.e., if $f$ is injective, then $g$ is injective?

Comment: Not sure I believe it.  Say $A=\{-1,1\}$ and $f$ is the usual inclusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterexample:  $A=\{-1,1\}$ and $f$ is the usual inclusion into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: can u explain a bit more if u dont mind

Comment: Not sure what there is to explain.  $f(-1)=-1,f(1)=1\implies g(-1)=4=g(1)$.  Hence $f$ is injective (plainly) but $g$ is not.

Comment: Lulu offered a counterexample. The converse (i.e. if $x \mapsto f(x)$ is injective, then $x \mapsto 3(f(x))^2 + 1$ is injective) is false, as this answer shows a function $f$ such that $3(f(x)^2) + 1$ is *not* injective.